How to draw the below table?

I want to draw the table attached. How to do

Would you mind sharing what you have tried so far?

Welcome to TeX.SX! On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Have a look at the tabularray package.

@close-voters: This is a new user! Please give time before closing!

You want five columns, but merging the second and third ones in the first three rows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| w{c}{0.5cm} | w{c}{1cm} | w{c}{1cm} | w{c}{2cm} | w{c}{2cm} |}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & \\
\hline
& & & & \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
& & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



+1. However, maybe replace all instances of \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{2cm}|}{} with either\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} or -- if one wants to be needlessly precise --   \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimeval{2cm+2\tabcolsep}}|}{}?

@Mico You're perfectly right.

Using the tabularray package is easier and results in more concise code compared to using w columns with the traditional tabular environment.


Full code
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { X[.5] *{2}{X[1, c]} *{2}{X[2, c]} },
    hlines, vlines,
    cell{1-3}{2} = {c=2}{},% as if it were a single column
    cell{4}{2} = {r=2}{},
}
    text & text      & (ignored) & text & text\\
    text & text      & (ignored) & text & text\\
    text & text      & (ignored) & text & text\\
    text & text      & text      & text & text\\
    text & (ignored) & text      & text & text\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


Just curious: Why specify 7 columns rather than 5?

The OP didn't clarify whether they wanted to write in it, so I typeset what seemed simplest from a programming perspective. However, I have updated the answer nonetheless.

You can construct this by TeX primitive commands \vbox, \hbox, \vrule, \hrule.
\def\bx{\hbox to6em{}}
\def\by{\hbox to2em{}}
\def\vx{\vrule height.9em depth.4em\kern-.4pt}

\vbox{\hrule \offinterlineskip
  \hbox{\vx \by \vx \bx \vx \bx \vx \bx \vrule}\hrule
  \hbox{\vx \by \vx \bx \vx \bx \vx \bx \vrule}\hrule
  \hbox{\vx \by \vx \bx \vx \bx \vx \bx \vrule}\hrule
  \hbox{\vx \by \vx \bx \vx \bx \vx \bx \vrule}
  \hbox{\vrule height.4pt width2em \vrule \kern6em \vrule width12em}
  \hbox{\vx \by \vx \bx \vx \bx \vx \bx \vrule}\hrule
}

\bye


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cc|cc|cc|}[hlines,columns-width=6mm]
&&&&&&\\
\\
\\
& \Block[borders=right]{2-1}{} \\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


With 5 columns (instead of 7):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|w{c}{6mm}|w{c}{6mm}w{c}{6mm}|w{c}{12mm}|w{c}{12mm}|}[hlines]
&&&&\\
\\
\\
& \Block[borders=right]{2-1}{} \\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


Does this table feature 7 individual columns (rather than just 5)?

@Mico: You are right. The OP probably prefers 5 columns. I will modify my answer.

From your description it is not clear whether you want to treat the column2-rows4-5 as two cells with no border between them or as a single cell. In the former case, egreg's answer works nicely. In the latter case, you can use multirow package and change a single line in egreg's code (marked below):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| w{c}{0.5cm} | w{c}{1cm} | w{c}{1cm} | w{c}{2cm} | w{c}{2cm} |}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{2cm}|}{} & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{2cm}|}{} & & \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{2cm}|}{} & & \\
\hline
1 & \multirow{2}{*}{2} & 3 & 4 & 5\\   %this line merges cells
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
1 &  & 3& 4& 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

You can see the difference in the pictures below.



Here's a solution which is very similar to Emanuele's answer using the tabularray package because of its ease of typesetting, but I've tried to adapt egreg's approach to it:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={ X[0.5cm, c] X[1cm, c] X[1cm, c] X[2cm, c] X[2cm, c] }, % Width and placement
    hlines, vlines,
    cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{}, cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{}, cell{3}{2} = {c=2}{}, % Merged all cells of 2nd column with the next column (3rd) up until the 3rd row
    cell{4}{2} = {r=2}{} % Merged the cell in the 4th row of the 2nd column with the row below it (5th)
}
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Output:


One more with tblr of tabularray package, but with really MWE:
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=100mm,% 1+1.5+1.5+3+3
             hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { X[0.5, c] *{2}{X[c]} *{2}{X[2, c]} },
             cell{1-3}{2} = {c=2}{},
             cell{Y}{2} = {r=2}{},
             }
    text & text &      & text & text\\
    text & text &      & text & text\\
    text & text &      & text & text\\
    text & text & text & text & text\\
    text &      & text & text & text\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


